# Eloquent query in Laravel 4 how to show single post with comments from specific category

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

many hours I can not do the following:
i have tables:
**categories:** id, name
**posts:** id, category_id, title, text, hidden('1'or'0'), crated_at, update_at, etc....
**comments:** id, post_id, user_id, text, created_at
**users:** id, name, etc...

My Models:

```
class Category extends Eloquent {

    public function posts() {
        return $this->hasMany('Post');
    }
}

class Comment extends Eloquent {

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Post');
    }

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('user');
    }

}

class Post extends Eloquent {

    public function category() {

        return $this->belongsTo('category');
    }

    public function comments() {
        return $this->hasMany('Comment');
    }
}

class User extends Eloquent {
    public function comments() {
        return $this->hasMany('comment');
    }

}
```

Ok, i have 2 categories and can show all posts from specific category like

```
$posts = Category::find(1)->posts()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->where('hidden', '=', 0)->paginate(5);
```

And now i want to create a query of single post but i don't know how.
i want:
1. when i type /news/1 it show me 1th post from 1 category, but if i type /news/2 it's show no post because 2th post in other category
2. Post has many comments and basically i know how it to do, anyway.
3. If post is hidden it should not to be showed by url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public function show($id) {
    // This code works, but I could not make a pagination for comments
    //$posts = Category::find(1)->posts()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->where('hidden', '=', 0)->where('id', '=', $id)->with('comments', 'comments.user')->get();
    //Following code works as i want
    $posts = Category::find(1)->posts()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->where('hidden', '=', 0)->where('id', '=', $id)->get();
    $comments = Comment::where('post_id', '=', $id)->paginate(10);
    //This line adds +1 to views, but on every click. Need to work on that
    //if (count($posts) > 0) Post::where('id', '=', $id)->increment('views');
    return View::Make('news.view')->with(array('posts' => $posts, 'comments' => $comments));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a function and pass in the post number as `$id`, or whatever.

Im just naming the function `news` here and passing the $id,  but yours will be different cuz I don't know your controller / page structure....but its along these lines.

```
 public function news($id){

$posts = Category::find(1)->posts()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->where('hidden', '=', 0)->where('id','=',$id)->get();
 print_r($posts);
}
```

Now it will find that specific post in that category 1......if the post doesn't exist in the category, it shouldn't return anything.

So if you go to `news/1` it will show, and if you go to `news/2` nothing will show, because the Category still stayed at (1)

Comment: yep, almost what I need but ->with('comments')
And now i have two-dimensional array with post and all his commets, but i can't access to comments array to do "foreach" 
tried 
foreach ($posts->comments as $comment) {
echo $comment->text
}
but has no results - "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: I believe its because $comment isnt an object what happens if you do echo $comment['text'];

Comment: only if<code>        foreach ($posts[0]['comments'] as $comment) {
            echo $comment['text'];
        }</code>whether there is no other way?

Comment: Well, if I get a single post in this way $post[0]['title'] and etc and try to change page id to wrong it says " Undefined offset: 0  " What can be do about that?

Comment: You would just check the array if its empty first before you do your foreach loop....that way if its empty it doesnt try execute the foreach